# select last of an item for each user in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the last entry for each user but the customer_id is a hash 'ASAG#...' order by customer_id destroys the query. Is there an alternative?

```
Select Distinct On (l.customer_id)
     l.customer_id
    ,l.created_at
    ,l.text
From likes l
Order By l.customer_id, l.created_at Desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query already appears to be working, q.v. here:

## Demo

I don't know why your current query is not generating the results you would expect.  It should return one distinct record for every customer, corresponding to the more recent one, given your `ORDER BY` statement.

In any case, if it does not do what you want, an alternative would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` here with a partition by user.  The inner query assigns a row number to each user, with the value `1` going to the most recent record for each user.  Then the outer query retains only the latest record.

```
SELECT
    t.customer_id,
    t.created_at,
    t.text
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM likes
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

To speed up the inner query which uses `ROW_NUMBER()` you can try adding a composite index on the `customer_id` and `created_at` columns:

```
CREATE INDEX yourIdx ON likes (customer_id, created_at);
```

Comment: yeah, this is great. any suggestions on how to speed it up? it take about 30 seconds right now.

Comment: Try adding a composite index on both `customer_id` and `created_at`.